# Как привязать прокси к vk_api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Вопрос собственно в названии, добавить нечего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передайте сессию `requests` с подключенным прокси одноимённым параметром при инициализации `VkApi`.

***Пример:***

```py
from requests import Session
from vk_api import VkApi

session = Session()
session.proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'}  # Замените на свой

vk_session = VkApi(session=session)
```

---

`SOCKS` настраивается так же, но требует установки `pysocks`:

```py
pip install pysocks
```

***Пример:***

```py
# Замените на свой
session.proxies.update({'http': 'socks5://user:password@127.0.0.1:8000'})
```

Comment: А как прикрутить socks прокси, не подскажете, пожалуйста?

Comment: @xkrystalll Также — просто замените протокол. Может потребоваться установить `pysocks`. Обновил ответ.